# How to use both GIN index in one query

Tags: postgresql

I use (PostgreSQL) 11.8. And I have table brand with GIN index

```
      CREATE INDEX bn_custom_index ON brand
      USING GIN(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', brand_name));
```

And I created GIN index with `gin_trgm_ops`:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
    CREATE INDEX brand_trgm_idx ON brand USING GIN (brand_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

And the table products with `GIN` index:

```
    CREATE INDEX npd_swedish_custom_index ON products
    USING GIN(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', name||price||description))
```

Then, in query where I use `fulltext search` only for products table.

In analyze section I found `npd_swedish_custom_index` index and this is correct and expected behavior.

[image]

The explain command with my select:

```
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    SELECT
            DISTINCT brand_alias.id,
            brand_alias.brand_name AS "brandName",
            brand_alias.created_at AS "createdAt"
    FROM brand brand_alias
    INNER JOIN products products_alias ON products_alias.brand_relation_id = brand_alias.id

            JOIN to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'ball:*') query_search
            ON to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description) @@ query_search  
            GROUP BY brand_alias.id
     ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC                                          
            LIMIT 10
            OFFSET 0;
```

But when I added additional `fulltext search` by `brand` table, as below:

```
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
    SELECT
            DISTINCT brand_alias.id,
            brand_alias.brand_name AS "brandName",
            brand_alias.created_at AS "createdAt"
    FROM brand brand_alias
    INNER JOIN products products_alias ON products_alias.brand_relation_id = brand_alias.id

            JOIN to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'ball:*') query_search
            ON to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description) @@ query_search  
        JOIN to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Louis:*') query_search_facet
        ON to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',brand_alias.brand_name) @@ query_search_facet
            GROUP BY brand_alias.id
     ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC                                          
                    LIMIT 10
                    OFFSET 0;
```

I did not found in analyze section using `npd_swedish_custom_index` but found `bn_custom_index`. Why `npd_swedish_custom_index` and  `bn_custom_index` inidexes did not used both for this query?

Mentions about product `to_tsquery` in analyze looks like:

```
     Join Filter: (to_tsvector('swedish'::regconfig, (((products_alias.name)::text || (products_alias.price)::text) || products_alias.description)) @@ query_search.query_search)
```

The result is:
[image]

I thinking maybe this is because I use the same way with `JOIN to_tsquery` and try to use `pg_trgm` way.

```
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm; 
    CREATE INDEX brand_trgm_idx ON brand USING GIN (brand_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

And then, I tried this approach:

```
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    SELECT
            DISTINCT brand_alias.id,
            brand_alias.brand_name AS "brandName",
            brand_alias.created_at AS "createdAt"
    FROM brand brand_alias
    INNER JOIN products products_alias ON products_alias.brand_relation_id = brand_alias.id

            JOIN to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'ball:*') query_search
            ON to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', products_alias.name||products_alias.price||products_alias.description) @@ query_search  
            WHERE brand_alias.brand_name % 'Louis'
            GROUP BY brand_alias.id
     ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC                                          
                    LIMIT 10
                    OFFSET 0;
```

But, in this case I still did not find `npd_swedish_custom_index`.

I want know in this case my index from products table `npd_swedish_custom_index` make profit for this query and how to use the both index in one query?

Comment: You should post text as text, not as images.  Especially not as images in which much of the useful info has been truncated at the edge of the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an index, probably a highly selective and efficient one, being used on products.brand_relation_id.  Throwing usage of a 2nd index on top of that one is unlikely to be very efficient in this scenario.  The machinery to combine indexes has an overhead, and if it doesn't get you a lot of extra selectivity it is probably not worth it.

On a test/dev server, you would drop the index it is currently using and see what it changes to instead.  Maybe it will use one GIN index from each table, and then hash join those two results on the join condition.

Is your goal to make the query faster, or just to force it to use your favorite index even if that is slower?

Comment: my goal make query faster